# What is the proper way to create DTO in a reactive manner?

Tags: spring-boot, dto, reactive, reactor, reactor-netty

I use SpringBoot and I have some Reactive APIs (Controller call a service which call a repository based on MongoReactiveRepositories)

As I don't want the user to directly see my models objects, I would like to have DTOs.

One DTO can be based on the information of several models.

Ex: Given two Model Items

```
ItemA:
 infoA:String

ItemB:
 infoB:String
```

I want to create a single DTO item

```
ObjectDTO:
 infoA: String
 infoB: List<ItemB>
```

What is the proper way to reactively map data between my objects model and a DTO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Mono.zip(https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to combine 2 results into one.

```
return Mono.zip(repo1.getItemA(), repo2.getItemB(),
   (itemA, itemB) -> new ObjectDTO(itemA.getInfoA(), itemB.getInfoB())
);
```

The methods returning itemA and itemB should ofcourse return a `Mono`.